# Detecting if inside a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, grouping

I would like to define the `\DrawLine` macro below so that it can be invoked from *within* a `{tikzpicture}` environment or from *outside*:

```
\newcommand*{\DrawLine}[1]{%
  \IfInTikzPic{}{\tikzpicture[remember picture]}
      \draw[ultra thick, ->, #1] (0,) -- (1,1) node [right] {output of DrawLine};
  \IfInTikzPic{}{\endtikzpicture}%
}
```

This works fine when invoked from within a `{tikzpicture}`, but not when it is invoked from outside (line is commented in the MWE).  Invoking it from outside yields the error:

> Missing \endgroup inserted.

[image]

The MWE below uses the first reference below. The other two references also fail on the commented out test case.

### References:

- [Detecting if inside a tikzpicture node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121303/4301). Even though this solution is for detecting within a node, it appears to work to detect if you are within a `\tikzpicture` (as the commented out code in the MWE shows).
- [Is there a (simple) way to find out if a command is executed in a tikzpicture environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412456/4301).
- [How can I check if the current code is inside a certain environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18652/4301).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfInTikzPic}[2]{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121309/4301
  \ifx\pgfpictureid\@undefined#2\else#1\fi%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\DrawLine}[1]{%
  \IfInTikzPic{}{\tikzpicture[remember picture]}
      \draw[ultra thick, ->, #1] (0,) -- (1,1) node [right] {output of DrawLine};
  \IfInTikzPic{}{\endtikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
%%% The commented out code here is to show that \IfInTikzPic works as desired
%%% (in a tikzpicture, outside of a \node).
%%%

%\textbf{IfInTikzPic}\par
%\IfInTikzPic{inside}{outside}
%
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%  \IfInTikzPic{\draw [red, ultra thick]}{\draw [blue, ultra thick]} (0,0) -- (1,0);
%\end{tikzpicture}
%
%\medskip% --------------------------
\textbf{DrawLine}: Actual Output\par

%\DrawLine{blue}% <---- How do I get this case to work?

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip% --------------------------
\textbf{DrawLine}: Desired Output\par

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-certain-environment perhaps

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412456/is-there-a-simple-way-to-find-out-if-a-command-is-executed-in-a-tikzpicture-en

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That works for all _but_ the commented out case below (yields a different error message though: `Undefined control sequence`).

Comment: @marmot: Yep, that also works for all _but_ the commented out case below and produces the same error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example defines `\IfInTikzPic` to check the `curr`ent `envir`onment against `tikzpicture` and define a `\tikzstart`...`\tikzend` pair accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\@tikzenvironment{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\IfInTikzPic}{%
  \edef\tikzstart{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\@tikzenvironment\else
      \noexpand\tikzpicture[remember picture]%
    \fi
  }%
  \edef\tikzend{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\@tikzenvironment\else
      \noexpand\endtikzpicture%
    \fi
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\DrawLine}[1]{%
  \IfInTikzPic
  \tikzstart
    \draw[ultra thick, ->, #1] (0,) -- (1,1) node [right] {output of DrawLine};
  \tikzend%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textbf{DrawLine}: Actual Output\par

\DrawLine{blue}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip% --------------------------

\textbf{DrawLine}: Desired Output\par

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You could also group the `tikzpicture` if needed:

```
\newcommand{\IfInTikzPic}{%
  \edef\tikzstart{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\@tikzenvironment\else
      \noexpand\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]%
    \fi
  }%
  \edef\tikzend{%
    \ifx\@currenvir\@tikzenvironment\else
      \noexpand\end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi
  }%
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfInTikzPic}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121309/4301
  \ifx\pgfpictureid\@undefined
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\DrawLine}[1]{%
  \IfInTikzPic
   {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \draw[ultra thick, ->, #1] (0,) -- (1,1) node [right] {output of DrawLine};
   \end{tikzpicture}}%
    {\draw[ultra thick, ->, #1] (0,) -- (1,1) node [right] {output of DrawLine};}%
}

\begin{document}
%%% The commented out code here is to show that \IfInTikzPic works as desired
%%% (in a tikzpicture, outside of a \node).
%%%

\textbf{IfInTikzPic}\par
\IfInTikzPic{inside}{outside}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \IfInTikzPic{\draw [red, ultra thick]}{\draw [blue, ultra thick]} (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip% --------------------------
\textbf{DrawLine}: Actual Output\par

\DrawLine{blue}% <---- How do I get this case to work?

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip% --------------------------
\textbf{DrawLine}: Desired Output\par

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Or this version which directly forces tikz rather than having an if-then-else construct

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ensuretikz}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121309/4301
  \ifx\pgfpictureid\@undefined
    \expandafter\tikzify
     \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\def\tikzify#1{\begin{tikzpicture}#1\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand*{\DrawLine}[1]{%
    \ensuretikz
    {\draw[ultra thick, ->, #1] (0,) -- (1,1) node [right] {output of DrawLine};}%
}

\begin{document}
%%% The commented out code here is to show that \IfInTikzPic works as desired
%%% (in a tikzpicture, outside of a \node).
%%%




\medskip% --------------------------
\textbf{DrawLine}: Actual Output\par

\DrawLine{blue}% <---- How do I get this case to work?

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip% --------------------------
\textbf{DrawLine}: Desired Output\par

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{blue}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawLine{orange}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought it might have something to dot with the dreaded _expansion_ issues!

Comment: @PeterGrill I think the main error was `\IfInTikzPic{}{\endtikzpicture}%`  as by that point you are always in a tikz picture, you need to know if you started it or if you were already in one.

Comment: Opsss..., thats a bit embarrassing. I'd prefer to not duplicate the drawing code though.

Comment: @PeterGrill duplicating it isn't needed, I could post a variant without, i just started by simplifying it

Comment: @PeterGrill plan b posted