# What is the proper way to change the font inside tikzpicture environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, latex3

I would like to be able to measure some dimensions while in the `tikzpicture` environment.

Here is the MWE to demonstrate my intentions:

```
\documentclass {article}
\RequirePackage [utf8] {inputenc}

\RequirePackage {tikz}
\RequirePackage {expl3}

\begin {document}
    %\begin {tikzpicture}
        \ExplSyntaxOn
            \dim_new:N \height
            \settoheight {\height} {\fontsize {18} {21.6} \selectfont something}
            \dim_log:N \height
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    %\end {tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

When `tikzpicture` is commented out, the `height` is properly measured.
However, once the `tikzpicture` environment is enabled, the `height` has the value `0.0pt`.

Judging by the log and similar questions on the internet, this is happening because `tikzpicture` environment sets the font to `nullfont`, which doesn't have any character in it.
Therefore, it's impossible to measure the dimensions of the glyphs.

I have tried to change the font inside the `tikzpicture` environment by adding:

```
\renewcommand {\encodingdefault} {OT1}
\renewcommand {\familydefault} {\rmdefault}
\renewcommand {\rmdefault} {cmr}
\renewcommand {\seriesdefault} {m}
\renewcommand {\shapedefault} {n}

\fontencoding {\encodingdefault}
\fontfamily {\familydefault}
\fontseries {\seriesdefault}
\fontshape {\shapedefault}
\selectfont
```

Unfortunately, this didn't change the outcome.

The only thing, that did change the outcome, was adding `\font\nullfont=cmr18`.
But this approach has downsides:

1. It really looks like a bad and unsecure code.
2. `height` differs between disabled `tikzpicture` and enabled `tikzpicture` + new `nullfont`.
3. Looks like redefinition of `nullfont` and also ignores this part of code: `\fontsize {18} {21.6}`.

How can I change the font to global one, only when performing these measurements inside `tikzpicture` and change it back to `nullfont` afterwards?

Comment: Inside a `tikzpicture` the text is gobbled (`\nullflont`) unless you put in in a node, where you can use `font` or `node font`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459853/121799) for a very related question.

Comment: @marmot I understand that, but then how can I measure dimensions of the text and store it into a variable, if I can only do it inside a node?

Comment: `\begin{advertizing}` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459858/121799 `\end{advertizing}`. ;-) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I still have no knowledge of a lot of the things done there, but it seems like it is not sufficient for my use case. I need to just calculate dimension and store it into a variable, while inside `tikzpicture`. I don't want to draw a node with that value. That value will be used later just for calculating the position of next drawing. Is that even possible? I thought font changing will be easy enough, but it doesn't look like it now :D

Comment: The nodes are not necessary. All you need to is to issue an `\begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%` before you define the box and `\end{pgfinterruptpicture}%` afterwards.  `\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
        \ExplSyntaxOn
            \dim_new:N \height
            \settoheight{\height}{\fontsize{18}{21.6} \selectfont something}
   \global\height=\height
            \dim_log:N \height
        \ExplSyntaxOff
 \end{pgfinterruptpicture}% 
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \typeout{\the\height}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed even though I asked for something else :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this if others feel the current question is too similar to e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459853/121799). There are two issues. First and foremost, the text in a tikzpicture (which is not in nodes) will be gobbled. So you need to interrupt the `tikzpicture`. And then if you measure things inside a group, you somehow need to broadcast the stuff outside. I will use `\global` here but of course there are alternatives.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfinterruptpicture}%
        \ExplSyntaxOn
            \dim_new:N \height
            \settoheight{\height}{\fontsize{18}{21.6} \selectfont something}
            \global\height=\height
            \dim_log:N \height          
        \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{pgfinterruptpicture}%  
    %\node{\the\height}; %<- requires that the height is smuggled out of the    group
    \end{tikzpicture}

    The height of the text inside the \texttt{tikzpicture} is \the\height. Note
    that we had to globalize it because otherwise the height would be local.

\end{document}
```

[image]